# Unresponsive Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, linux

I have Geoserver 2.8.2 running on Tomcat7 on an Ubuntu 14.04 virtual machine. I started adding a large number (off the top of my head, about 5000) of smallish (roughly 2 to 10 Mb) Geotiffs as layers using a Python script and the gsconfig module.

After saving a style I was working on, the web interface became unresponsive. I restarted Tomcat but still no response from either GeoServer's web interface or from Tomcat's one.

So I stopped Tomcat and restarted. The whole server became unresponsive to pings or login attempts. The syadmin restarted the virtual machine, with apparently no data loss. Tomcat is up and running but the web interfaces for it and GeoServer are still unresponsive. The logs don't show anything particular, but catalina.out does - I have more than 50Mb of logs looking like this:

11 Mar 11:41:41 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage 'es502c_R5_C1_4_T_2795_sec', enabled
11 Mar 11:41:41 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage 'es502c_R5_C1_4_T_2795_sec'
11 Mar 11:41:42 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'es502c_R5_C1_4_T_2795_sec'
11 Mar 11:41:42 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded store 'cz010c_R9_C1_3_T_2751_sec', enabled
11 Mar 11:41:42 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage store 'cz010c_R9_C1_3_T_2751_sec'
11 Mar 11:41:42 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage 'cz010c_R9_C1_3_T_2751_sec', enabled
11 Mar 11:41:42 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage 'cz010c_R9_C1_3_T_2751_sec'

...and so on. And it is still growing. These are the layers I was adding, but my Python script is definitely not running.

I am reluctant to restart Tomcat again, to avoid freezing the server again.

What is going on? It looks a bit like Geoserver is trying to catch up on its logging, but could it be stuck in a long loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it some time. Or does the log show all your layers "Loaded" already? Geoserver does some processing after the layers are added.

You could also check your server's performance. Is the CPU maxed out? Is IO at the limit. Etc.

To avoid overloading it, why not do small batches at a time.

Comment: Very reasonable suggestions, but the CPU does not appear particularly taxed: the remote desktop client is taking more CPU than Java. I would gladly do the job in small batches, but I would have to stop whatever's going on first, and as I mentioned my original Python script is not running, I restarted Tomcat twice, restarted the virtual machine, got it frozen, got it restarted again, and *then* GeoServer still keeps going. There's nothing else obvious I can stop or suspend.

Comment: Update: after a day and a half, it ended. GeoServer was going through all the 60000 Geotiffs with the same style and altering them. This caused the lack of responses - the server was just overwhelmed!

Comment: Told you so! ;) Glad it got resolved.